# Camera Stuck and Separated

Tags: camera

I am very new to Blender, sorry if the question is dumb. My camera viewer seems to be separated from its body, and from tutorials I've seen, it shouldn't be separated. When selected, only the viewer moves, and the rest is just stuck in the origin point. I thought maybe I really messed things up and actually deleted Blender and reinstalled it, but the problem remains.
What should I do?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Although it doesn't answer what happened, a quick solution would be to delete the camera object(s) and add a new one.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I tried that, and to close and reopen the software, but it's still like that...

Comment: If you hit 0 on the numpad (or f3 for quick search and type view camera) you can get the camera view. If you're able to see from the viewer when you move it around, you're probably good until someone finds a real solution to the visual error (if that's all it is).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I did that. As you said, it must be just a visual error because I can see through the viewer just fine. It's just the camera icon that's stuck. I have the same error also with the light - the icon is stuck at the center, and when I try to move it, an invisible light moves, and the actual icon stays where it is (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Yeah that's weird. There's a bunch of stuff you could mess around with but this sounds like a bug (could be wrong though). The only thing I would suggest is if you have time, try downloading version 2.90 and see if it works.

Comment: I don't know how this is possible, but I've downloaded version 2.90 and deleted the newer version, and it's still the same. There must be something wrong with my computer, or something I accidentally did or wronged someone in a past life or something... I guess I'll just have to work around it.